# Initializing global object in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

In summary, my problem is how do you easily make a connection resource a global variable? To be specific, I'd like to open a Redis queue connection and would like to use that in multiple functions without the hassle of passing it as a parameter, i.e.'

```
#===============================================================================
# Global variables
#===============================================================================
REDIS_QUEUE <- how to initialize
```

Then, in my main function, have

```
# Open redis queue connection to server
REDIS_QUEUE = redis.StrictRedis(host=SERVER_IP, port=6379, db=0)
```

And then use `REDIS_QUEUE` in multiple functions, e.g.

```
def sendStatusMsgToServer(statusMsg):
    print "\nSending status message to server:"
    print simplejson.dumps(statusMsg)
    REDIS_QUEUE.rpush(TLA_DATA_CHANNEL, simplejson.dumps(statusMsg))
```

I thought `REDIS_QUEUE = none` would work but it gives me

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rpush'
```

I'm new to Python, what's the best way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean "the main program"?  Where are you defining global variables if not in the main program?  (That is, why don't you just do `REDIS_QUEUE = redis.StrictRedis(...)` right away.)

Comment: Place the instance in `module`.  Then, in other files, `import` it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "main function".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the value of a global variable from inside a function, you need to use the `global` statement.  So in your main function:

```
def main():
    global REDIS_QUEUE
    REDIS_QUEUE = redis.StrictRedis(host=SERVER_IP, port=6379, db=0)
    # whatever else
```

Note that there's no need to "initialize" the variable outside `main` before doing this, although you may want to just to document that the variable exists.